# How to display custom number of posts on archive page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change numbrer of posts displayed only on my archive pages,
kindly let me know how to that, thank you.

This is the code from my archive.php

```
<div id="content-a">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
<div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
<div class="p-heading"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>
<div class="p-content"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<div class="p-info"><?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12"><?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to have different number of posts on archive pages. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php and change the no of post from 100 instead how much you want to display.

```
function wpsites_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_query' );
```

try this

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'archive');
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: Thank you. If you want to apply this rule for search results as well, do you just add is_search after is_archive?

Comment: check I have updated answer but you should try it before last change.